# Application of Banach-Alaoglu

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Z$ be two Banach spaces, and considr the space $\mathcal{L}(X,Z^*)$ of all bounded linear maps from $X$ into $Z^*$. In this space we define the weak* operator topology $\tau$.
Show that any subset of $\mathcal{L}(X,Z^*)$ which is norm-bounded and $\tau$-closed is $\tau$-compact. 
(This should be direct result of Banach-Alaoglu and Tychonoff Theroem)

This is my firs time with operator topology (already I studied usual strong, weak and weak* topologies), I know the statments of both theorems but I have no idea how to do it.
Moreover I cannot imagine why it follows from Banach-Alaoglu (why those subsets are from unit ball in dual space?)